# is there any api to get the event details for a specific offense in QRadar

Tags: rest, automation, rest-assured

I'm exploring out for an api which gets the event details for a specific offense in QRadar. I'm able to filter the event associated for a specific offense using the ariel endpoints but not getting the drill-down details for a specific event. I need it for my api automation usig rest assured.

Answer (score 2):

If you execute an AQL search via the API to get the events associated with the offense you can directly specify which fields of the events you want to get in the results.

Example AQL

```sql
SELECT qidname(qid) as 'eventname', logsourcename(logsourceid) as 'log source', dateformat(starttime, 'YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm'), username
FROM events
WHERE INOFFENSE(123456)
LAST 10 days
```

This search returns the event name, the log source name, the timestamp and the username. These fields should all be accessible in the JSON returned by the API.